# Automatically chmod a+r on files copied into my (OSX FUSE / sshfs mounted) VFS

Tags: file-permissions, chmod

I have a virtual Linux machine running LAMP.

On my MacBook I've mapped `~/remoteFS` to this machine's `~/` using OSX FUSE & `sshfs`.

i.e. First I install OSX FUSE.  then I do:

```
sshfs  pi@46.108.38.186:/home/pi  ~/RemoteFS/droplet__home_pi
```

The problem is that files I copy onto the remote system don't have public read permission, so I have to `ssh` in and `chmod a+r` on them.

Someone on IRC suggested adding `-o umask=0022` to the sshfs command, and this sometimes fixes the problem. But not always!

Can anyone suggest why this solution is intermittent?  And is there any way to make it robust?